# TypeScript self reference

Tags: typescript, vue.js, phpstorm

I have a Vue plugin which allow to access constants object in templates of .vue files as shortcut:

```
<template>
    <span>{{ $consts.HELLO }}</span>
</template>

export default {
    constants: {HELLO: 'hello there!'},
};
```

`$consts` here is a link to `$options.constants`.

How can I describe this functionality in TypeScript? My version is:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface Vue {
        readonly constants?: object
        readonly $consts: Vue['$options']['?constants'] // ???
    }
}
```

But TypeScript show me this error:

> TS2339: Property '?constants' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions  , DefaultMethods , DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition  >, Record...>>'.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your interface does not have `$options` property

Comment: This works as expected https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGoFcUG8BQzlQRwAmA9iADYCeyC5AzmHOPQPwBcypARgFYQIweAkTKUaAEjohG9ThggBtAOTTGzMPWUBdHAF8cOMFQAOKAMIALAQGtkAXjSYVUhpp3IA9J+Rx6yCAAPM0EIYmQAWgA+Lj4BMGQAH2R0EGIIGFAwoA

Comment: @captain-yossarian, $options is a standard vue component prop of type ComponentOptions<Vue>. in this prop will be merged all not documented props declared in vue component object (like "constants", or any other unreserved name)

Comment: Please check the official doc (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins) - does it work for you?

Comment: @lena tnx for link. but my case is more complicated, because i should reference on the prop "$options" which don't have "constants" field described in vue package (as expected)

Comment: not sure I follow you... what about augmenting `'vue/types/options'` as suggested in the docs?

Comment: @lena sorry, my bad i missed this. sounds like this do the trick! i think phpStorm messed up little bit too. should check code in another IDE

Comment: the error comes from the compiler, not sure how it's related to PHPstorm

Answer (score 0):

@lena was shared this link to the Vue official instruction:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

In my case I need to extend `ComponentOptions` like this

```
declare module 'vue/types/options' {
  interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
    constants?: {}
  }
}
```

and remove question mark from this line

```
readonly $consts: Vue['$options']['?constants']
```

so now in phpStorm *.vue files IDE is not warning about `Unresolved variable or type $consts`